# Set containment for leaflet L.Draggable object

Tags: jquery, leaflet, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a draggable window (this one in my case https://github.com/mapshakers/leaflet-control-window) on a map whose draggable area i want to constrain with a map frame to prevent it from going outside of the visible space and not ability to drag it back.

```
var draggable = new L.Draggable(this._container,this._containerTitleBar);
draggable.enable();
```

It's created using the code above, but there is no ability to pass a containment element as it's provided in jQuery

```
$('#elem').draggable({axis: 'y', containment : [0,containmentTop,0,containmentBottom] });
```

I'm sure there must be a way of constraining the drag area using L.Draggable not using Jquery's draggable instead of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the showOn function:

```
marker.off();
marker.on('click',function(){

        var win =  L.control.window(map,{title:'Hello world!',maxWidth:400,modal: true})
                .content('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ac sollicitudin eros, ut imperdiet felis. Pellentesque pretium mi ante, et faucibus ipsum rutrum sed. Proin accumsan luctus consectetur. In sit amet purus id dui scelerisque ultricies non porta dui. Cras sit amet arcu non est efficitur molestie.')
                .prompt({callback:function(){alert('This is called after OK click!')}})
                //.show()

win.showOn = function(point){
        this.setContentMaxHeight();
        L.DomUtil.setPosition(this._container, L.point(Math.round(point[0]),Math.round(point[1]),true));

        var draggable = new L.Draggable(this._container,this._containerTitleBar);

        draggable.enable();
        draggable.off().on('drag',function(e){
        var pos = e.sourceTarget._newPos;
        var winwidth = map._container.clientWidth-win._container.clientWidth-16;
        var winheight = map._container.clientHeight-win._container.clientHeight-16;
        if(pos.x <= 0 || pos.y <=0 || pos.x >= winwidth || pos.y >= winheight){
            if(pos.x <= 0){
                pos.x = 0;
            }
            if(pos.y <= 0){
                pos.y = 0;
            }
            if(pos.x >= winwidth){
                pos.x = winwidth;
            }
            if(pos.y >= winheight){
                pos.y = winheight;
            }
            L.DomUtil.setPosition(win._container, L.point(pos.x,pos.y));
        }
    });

        L.DomUtil.addClass(this._wrapper, 'visible');
        this.fire('show');
        return this;
    }
    win.show();
    });
```

I used this page for testing: http://mapshakers.com/projects/leaflet-control-window/

Paste the code above in the developer console and then click on the marker

Comment: Thanks, i did it like this but with standard extending mechanism `L.Control.Window.include({
 showOn: function(point){...}
});`